# Ecto Model Serialize

Tags: elixir, ecto

It there a method that [`Ecto.Entity`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/ecto/Ecto.Entity.html) or [`Ecto.Model`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/ecto/Ecto.Model.html) provides that will return a `Dict` of the fields defined in the model and their values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `to_keywords` (it is the same function used by records).